# Synchronising with Core Audio Thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, performance, audio, core-audio

I am using the render callback of the ioUnit to store the audio data into a circular buffer:

```
OSStatus ioUnitRenderCallback(
                          void *inRefCon,
                          AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                          const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                          UInt32 inBusNumber,
                          UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                          AudioBufferList *ioData)
{
    OSStatus err = noErr;

    AMNAudioController *This = (__bridge AMNAudioController*)inRefCon;

    err = AudioUnitRender(This.encoderMixerNode->unit,
                          ioActionFlags,
                          inTimeStamp,
                          inBusNumber,
                          inNumberFrames,
                          ioData);

    // Copy the audio to the encoder buffer
    TPCircularBufferCopyAudioBufferList(&(This->encoderBuffer), ioData, inTimeStamp, kTPCircularBufferCopyAll, NULL);

    return err;
}
```

I then want to read the bytes out of the circular buffer, feed them to libLame and then to libShout.
I have tried starting a thread and using NSCondition to make it wait until data is available but this causes all sorts of issues due to using locks on the Core Audio callback.

What would be the recommended way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

---

### More detail on how I implemented Adam's answer

I ended up taking Adam's advice and implemented it like so.

**Producer**

I use TPCircularBufferProduceBytes in the Core Audio Render callback to add the bytes to the circular buffer. In my case I have non-interleaved audio data so I ended up using two circular buffers.

**Consumer**

1. I spawn a new thread using pthread_create
2. Within the new thread create a new CFTimer and add it to the current
   CFRunLoop (an interval of 0.005 seconds appears to work well)
3. I tell the current CFRunLoop to run
4. Within my timer callback I encode the audio and send it to the server (returning quickly if no data is buffered)
5. I also have a buffer size of 5MB which appears to work well (2MB was giving me overruns). This does seem a bit high :/

Comment: It's not really clear from the example above which thread is blocking which other.  Blocking the Core Audio's thread is definitely not something you should do - otherwise potential exists for priority inversion.

Comment: @marko, If I use NSCondition to have my thread wait until the Core Audio thread sets a value, then the Core Audio thread locks up. I have since tried using semaphores and this appears to be the way to go.

Comment: What is TPCircularBufferCopyAudioBufferList doing? Does it block when the circular buffer is full? That could certainly explain the deadlock you are seeing.   Get your app in this state, interrupt it in the debugger and post the backtraces for the thread stacks here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you don't need NSCondition. You definitely don't want to block. The circular buffer implementation you're using is lock free and should do the trick. In the audio render callback, put the data into the buffer by calling `TPCircularBufferProduceBytes`. Then in the reader context (a timer callback is good, as hotpaw suggests), call `TPCircularBufferTail` to get the tail pointer (read address) and number of available bytes to read, and then call `TPCircularBufferConsume` to do the actual reading. Now you've done the transfer without taking any locks. Just make sure the buffer you allocate is large enough to handle the worst-case condition where your reader thread gets held off by the os for whatever reason, otherwise you can hit a buffer overrun condition and will lose data.

Comment: Thanks @Adam Bryant. A buffer size of 2,646,000bytes should hold 30 seconds of audio (surely this should be enough). But obviously I can't send this much in one packet (if the buffer gets full during the worst case). So, sending a fixed amount every iteration of my timer would be best, no? In that case, how much should I send (if my timer goes off every 200ms) 17,640bytes (200ms of audio) or should I send like 5 seconds of audio (having the timer return quickly if not enough bytes)?

Comment: I don't know all the details on what you're doing, but you need to be consuming audio at the same rate that it is produced, or else eventually you'll get a buffer under- or overrun. You know what rate audio is produced at - typically 44,100 samples per second. Now do the math and set your timer to wake up at the block size that your consumer (libShout?) prefers.

Comment: Once you're rolling, during most timer-wakeups you'll just consume one packet. But occasionally when you wake up you'll find that the consumer thread has been held off for whatever reason, and you need to consume multiple packets. You can determine this by the call to TPCircularBufferTail, which tells you how much audio is sitting there waiting for you to consume in the ring buffer ('availableBytes'). You basically want to drain the buffer each time you wake up to within the nearest consumer packet size. If there are multiple packets, just sit in a loop and send to libShout until all consumed.

Comment: In a client/server audio system, usually the receiving end accumulates a reservoir of audio from which it can draw if there are network stalls and audio isn't delivered for a while. So this means you need to prime the system with audio at the beginning before playing out.

Comment: How big you make this reservoir is dependent on how much network disruption you expect. The bigger the reservoir, the more the latency, though, so usually you try to find the right balance through experimentation.

Comment: Thanks Adam, one last question; how would I prime the system? In a non-live scenario I would imagine reading more data from the file for the first packet sent to the server would work, but in a live scenario where I can't access a larger chunk of data; how would that work?

Comment: Also, I have an encoder in the middle of the Core Audio and server/client stuff. So the flow currently is:
CoreAudio->Buffer->Encoder->Buffer->Server
Should the encoder be on the same timer as the client/server stuff or a separate timer? If the same timer, should I remove the second buffer and just send the data as it is encoded? E.g.
CoreAudio->Buffer->Encoder->Server
Thanks again Adam. I appreciate your help.

Comment: In a live scenario you stream input packets to the receiver until its reservoir gets full, and only *then* start playing them out to the speaker. That's why there's latency/delay between the live input and the sound actually coming out the speaker. As for the encoder it's probably fine to just do all the work in your timer wakeup. So just read the data from the CA ring buffer, do the encoding, and then put it in the outgoing buffer.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I will test all this out and accept your answer if all goes well.

Answer (score 4):

Use a repeating timer (NSTimer or CADisplayLink) to poll your lock-free circular buffer or FIFO.  Skip doing work if there is not enough data in the buffer, and return (to the run loop).  This works because you know the sample rate with high accuracy, and how much data you prefer or need to handle at a time, so can set the polling rate just slightly faster, to be on the safe side, but still be very close to the same efficiency as using conditional locks.

Using semaphores or locks (or anything else with unpredictable latency) in a real-time audio thread callback is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks @hotpaw2. So I should instantiate an NSRunLoop on my new thread, and then use an NSTimer running every 200ms or so?